# SQL Select query with postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I'd like to find all rows if is shows even once a particular value  with postgresql

For example :

```
id   TIT_CODE  CLI_NOM   CLI_PRENOM  CLI_ENSEIGNE
  1  M.        DUPONT    Alain       A
  2  M.        MARTIN    Marc        A
  3  M.        BOUVIER   Alain       V
  4  M.        DUBOIS    Paul        D
  5  M.        DREYFUS   Jean        C
  6  M.        FAURE     Alain       C
 11  M.        DUPONT    Alain       B
 12  M.        DUVAL     Arsène      B
 13  M.        DUPONT    Alain       B
 16  M.        CHABAUD   Daniel      A
```

And I want to have all rows where `CLI_ENSEIGNE = 'A`' but not only I want also the rows where `CLI_NOM` had a `CLI_ENSEIGNE = 'A'` even only one time:

We see here the Dupond had an A the a B

```
id   TIT_CODE  CLI_NOM   CLI_PRENOM  CLI_ENSEIGNE
  1  M.        DUPONT    Alain       A
  2  M.        MARTIN    Marc        A
 11  M.        DUPONT    Alain       B
 13  M.        DUPONT    Alain       B
 16  M.        CHABAUD   Daniel      A
```

I tried

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  table
WHERE 
CLI_ENSEIGNE = 'A' 
IN (CLI_NOM)
```

But it's saying that CLI_NOM doesn't exists

Comment: Is there a chance you have a `DUPONT Daniel` in the table?

Comment: And why isn't the row with `id=13` returned?

Comment: My mistake `id=13` should return

Comment: So please click "edit" left under your question to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

You where clause is incomplete and wouldn't work that way anyway.

You need a subselect for this:

```
SELECT   *
FROM the_table
WHERE cli_nom in (select cli_nom 
                  from the_table
                  where CLI_ENSEIGNE = 'A' );
```

alternatively a co-related sub-select with an `exists` clause:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM the_table t1
WHERE EXISTS (select 42
              from the_table t2
              where t2.cli_nom = t1.cli_nom
                and CLI_ENSEIGNE = 'A' );
```

Comment: omg  I've got it all wrong, thank you man

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`select * from x where cli_ensiegne ='A' or cli_nom in (select cli_nom from x where  cli_ensiegne ='A')`

Dupont had B 2 times.

Comment: Yes you're right I should have 2 rows of Dupond with B